# Extract part of text from string

Tags: string, reactjs

I am making a little doc's text searching app using technical stack `(react + nodejs + mongodb)`. 
For example if I type "chicken" on my search bar , i will have a whole article about chicken in my result (e.g : The most popular chicken's restaurant closed tonight because of lot of complain about chicken taste, all the employee lost their jobs  ) . 
The text is often too long to display , what i want to do is get an extract of the word with keyword like : "The most popular chicken's restaurant ... about chicken taste..." .

Do you have any idea about a function than can do that ?

`( keyword + max length in parameter)`. I tried with `substring` and `splice` and split but i can't find out the easiest way to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: you should show your efforts by sharing code, so that we can provide you hint, not whole code

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in addition to the comment of @MandeepSingh

Comment: Was any of the answer helpful to you? Feel free to [upvote & accept](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I have given a try to search for the keyword, take two intial words and two words after keyword and joined them with "...".

```js
var longString = "The most popular chicken's restaurant closed tonight because of lot of complain about chicken taste, all the employee lost their jobs";
var keyword = "chicken";

var allWords = longString.split(" ");
var indices = [];
allWords.forEach((word,index)=>{(word.indexOf(keyword)>=0) ? indices.push(index):""});
var newStrings = indices.map((i)=>{
    let temp="";
    temp=allWords[i-2]?allWords[i-2]+" ":"";
    temp+=allWords[i-1]?allWords[i-1]+" ":"";
    temp+=allWords[i];
    temp+=allWords[i+1]?" "+allWords[i+1]:"";
    temp+=allWords[i+2]?" "+allWords[i+2]:"";
    return temp;
  })

console.log("..."+newStrings.join("...")+"...");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression that matches your keyword and some words before and after it,  e.g. like this:

```
(?:\w+[\s,;:'".!?]+){0,3}(chicken)(?:[\s,;:'".!?]+\w+){0,3}
```

This will need some finetuning to take account of all possible punctuations, and other weird stuff of language that does not go well with the "word followed by space/comma,etc" schema. Take a look at the [ASCII character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), probably they will come handy.

```js
const test_str = ` The most popular chicken's restaurant closed tonight because of lot of complain about chicken taste, all the employee lost their jobs`;

function mySearchFunc(str, lookup) {
    const regex = new RegExp("(?:\\w+[\\s,;:'\".!?]+){0,3}" + lookup + "(?:[\\s,;:'\".!?]+\\w+){0,3}", "gm");
    let m;
    let result = [];
    while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }

        if (m)
            //console.log(`Found: ${m}`);
            result.push(m[0]);
    }
    return result.join(' ... ');
}

console.log(mySearchFunc(test_str, "chicken"));
```